# Why this Swift enumeration example in the GuideTour using switch on variable with only one value?

Tags: swift

This piece of code of [GuideTour](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html#ID465:%7E:text=what%20went%20wrong.-,enum%20ServerResponse,-%7B)

```swift
enum ServerResponse {
    case result(String, String)
    case failure(String)
}

let success = ServerResponse.result("6:00 am", "8:09 pm")
let failure = ServerResponse.failure("Out of cheese.")

switch success {
case let .result(sunrise, sunset):
    print("Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset is at \(sunset).")
case let .failure(message):
    print("Failure...  \(message)")
}
// Prints "Sunrise is at 6:00 am and sunset is at 8:09 pm."
```

is extreamly baffling.

Why do we need a switch here?

Because from the sample code, I thought the variable, `success` is already assigned with one value, which is `ServerResponse.result("6:00 am", "8:09 pm")`.

And using a `switch` on a variable with just one value is kind of strange...

Comment: Well, you're supposed to use your imagination here, and imagine that `success` comes from somewhere else, like a network response. You're not supposed to take the code *literally* ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The example is confusing. They're demonstrating how `switch` can be used to extract the associated values of the `enum`.

A better example would have been:

```
enum ServerResponse {
    case success(String, String)
    case failure(String)
}

let success = ServerResponse.success("6:00 am", "8:09 pm")
let failure = ServerResponse.failure("Out of cheese.")

let result = Bool.random() ? success : failure

switch result {
case let .success(sunrise, sunset):
    print("Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset is at \(sunset).")
case let .failure(message):
    print("Failure...  \(message)")
}
```

Then each time you run the code, you might get the `.success` or `.failure` result.  In either case, the `switch` extracts the values associated with the `enum` value and uses them to print.

---

Besides using `switch`, the other way to extract associated values of an enum is `case let`:

```
if case let .success(sunrise, sunset) = result {
    print("Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset is at \(sunset).")
}
```

This line says that if the assignment of `result` to the *pattern* `.success(sunrise, sunset)` succeeds, then print using the extracted values.  If the `result` were a `.failure`, then the `print` would be skipped.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. And one more thing, I just checked [language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127:~:text=would%20be%20ignored.-,Value%20Bindings,-A%20switch%20case) of `switch` and wonder if this section about its "Value binding" related to what you said there "how switch can be used to extract the associated values of the enum."

Comment: Yes. the value binding feature of switch can be used to unpack more than just enums, but that is how it is being used to extract the associated values.  More specifically see [Associated Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148) section under Enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the type of **success**, you will see that it is **ServerResponse** so as failure is. That means, when you switch success or failure, you have to handle all cases from **ServerResponse** enum.

Above code could be written

```
let success: ServerResponse = .result("6:00 am", "8:09 pm")
let failure: ServerResponse = .failure("Out of cheese.")

switch success {
case let .result(sunrise, sunset):
    print("Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset is at \(sunset).")
case let .failure(message):
    print("Failure...  \(message)")
}
```